Static factory action doesn’t appear on the table toolbar
I have defined a static factory action in the behavior definition as follows:

In the behavior projection, it is also enabled:

Here is how the static factory action is annotated in the meta extension

However, the action button does not appear at all on the app. Normally, it should appear in the Table Toolbar.

I also checked the metadata, and it seems to be correct:


I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

I'm looking at the following guide.
The only thing that stands out is you put your action annotations in the same array line/object as field annotations, while the guide has them in separate lines/objects.
In other words

You have: [{position: 10, type: #FOR_ACTION....}]
You should have: [{position: 10}, {type: #FOR_ACTION, ....}]

